# Загрузка файла на FTP С#

Tags: c#, ftp

Нужно загрузить файл на сервер
Нашел код, мучаю его. Ошибку не выдает, но и не загружает( В чем проблема

```
string ftpfullpath = "ftp://" + "ftp.name.ru" + "/papka/papka/1.txt";
FtpWebRequest ftp = (FtpWebRequest)FtpWebRequest.Create(ftpfullpath);
ftp.Credentials = new NetworkCredential("name", "pass");
ftp.KeepAlive = true;
ftp.UseBinary = true;
ftp.Proxy = null;
ftp.Method = WebRequestMethods.Ftp.UploadFile;
FileStream fs = File.OpenRead("d:\\1.txt");
byte[] buffer = new byte[fs.Length];
fs.Read(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
fs.Close();
Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();
ftpstream.Write(buffer, 0, buffer.Length);
ftpstream.Close();
```

Comment: Если, кто еще сможет подсказать, что происходит на каждом этапе, был бы еще больше благодарен.

Comment: Ошибку какую то мб кидает?

Comment: Нет, программа выполняется. Все хорошо. Но файла не появляется

Comment: А вы в отладчике программу запускали?

Comment: И что означает «кто еще сможет подсказать, что происходит на каждом этапе»? Это значит, что вы не прочитали документацию на код, а просто скопировали его без понимания? Тогда прочитайте документацию, в чём проблема?

Comment: Имелось ввиду что происходит на этапах KeepAlive и Stream ftpstream = ftp.GetRequestStream();

Comment: В итоге проблема решилась сама собой. Файлы появились. Причину сбоя не знаю. Спасибо за помощь всем, кто пытался

Answer (score 1):

Этот код не возвращает ошибку потому, что он не делает сам запрос. Запрос происходит при вызове метода `ftp.GetResponse()`, которого просто нет. Вот цитата из [msdn](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.net.ftpwebrequest(v=vs.110).aspx):

> Requests are sent to the server by calling the GetResponse method or its asynchronous counterparts, the BeginGetResponse and EndGetResponse methods.

Comment: На самом деле проблема была в просмоторщике FTP. Он почему-то не отображал обновленные файлы. А сам код полностью рабочий. Не хватает только try-catch чтобы прога не вылетала при проблемах со связью

Comment: @ЖеняВеденин все равно он может глотать ошибки - сам окончательный код ответа от сервера приходит и проверяется только в GetResponse, насколько я знаю. Вот стандартный пример: [How to: Upload Files with FTP](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms229715(v=vs.110).aspx)